# Argument type is not assignable to parameter type although it inherits

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, dbcontext, asp.net-identity-2

I tried to write a MVC application with ASP.net Identity from scratch. 
To do so I followed two tutorials from Ben Foster ([Tutorial Part1](http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-identity-stripped-bare-mvc-part-1) and [Tutorial Part2](http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-identity-stripped-bare-mvc-part-2))

But I stuck at the second tutorial - Configuring UserManager. The following line doesn't work for me:

```
    // configure the user manager
    UserManagerFactory = () =>
    {
        var usermanager = new UserManager<AppUser>(
            new UserStore<AppUser>(new AppDbContext()));
        ...
    }
```

Visual Studio underlines

```
new AppDbContext()
```

and shows me the following message:

> Argument type "MyProject.DbContext.AppDbContext" is not assignable to parameter type "System.Data.Entity.DbContext"

I don't understand why it doesn't work in my solution because I followed completely the tutorial. My AppDbContext looks like:

```
namespace MyProject.DbContext
{
    using MyProject.Models;

    using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

    public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
    {
        public AppDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }
    }
}
```

My User class:

```
namespace MyProject.Models
{
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

    public class User : IdentityUser
    {
        public string Name{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

I also downloaded the source code from Ben and tried to run it and it works without any problems. I think it doesn't make any difference that all of my files aren't located in the same folder?!

I hope you can help me. It's really frustrating if a simple tutorial doesn't work as it should...

Regards, winklerrr

Comment: Looks to me as though your AppDbContext needs to inherit System.Data.Entity.DbContext not looked at this but is this an interface maybe, or probably the base Entity Context, try changing AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User> to AppDbContext : System.Data.Entity.DbContext

Comment: AppDbContext inherits from IdentityDbContext, which inherits from DbContext. That's why I'm so confused...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by removing all the references that had something to do with owin and ASP.net Identity and re-added them again.

I think, the problem was caused by a discrepancy between the referenced dlls and the actual used dlls... (Played to much with the package manager console.)

Comment: I got the error to go away by uninstalling/reinstalling the EF 6.2 through the packet-manager

Answer (score 0):

Your `UserManager` takes `AppUser` as generic type: `UserManager<AppUser>`, when you db-context takes `User` as generic param. `AppUser` and `User` are not the same classes.

Your user-defining class should be the same everywhere.

Comment: Ah yeah, thanks... But that didn't solve the problem :/